# can not resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String)'

Tags: android

```
bted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String textoDolars=dolars.getText().toString();

                Double dolars=Double.parseDouble(textoDolars);

                Double euros=dolars*1.19;

                String textoEuros=String.valueOf(euros);


                euros.setText(textoEuros);



        }
    });
```

In this part  euros.setText(textoEuros);

can not resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String)'
How can ı handle this situation?

I tried another type of setText but ı couldnt find truth.Can you help me?

Comment: `dolars` is not an `TextView`.

Comment: post some code here .

Comment: post your code here

Comment: dolars is a textview or else ??

Comment: what kind of variable is dolar? and textoDolar? please as stated by previous comments post come code so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't provided us with full code I cannot determine the correct answer but here are couple of possibilities.

1. Set your command to the following textview.setText("sometext")
   You have to use "" when you are going to declare strings.
2. Dolars is not a textview
3. Is TextODolars a variable? If so, what kind? Maybe you have to use .toString to convert it

But please get into a habit of posting code for a clear answer

Comment: Nice explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling set text to a `Double` variable.
From your code: `euros.setText(textoEuros);`
`Double`is a wrapper class for the primitive type `double` and it does not have a method called setText.

You have a confusion there you probably are looking for a `TextView` on any subclass of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wan to display the value on the screen(?).

First you need a TextView.

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/output"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Now you can access it with some code to display the wanted value on the screen.

```
TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output)
//call setText
output.setText(textoEuros);
```